# Wrong OEM while trying to use FlashTool. (Android Rooting)

Tags: ubuntu, java, android, jre, jvm

I am trying to follow [this link](http://duopetalflower.blogspot.in/2012/08/flashtool-in-ubuntu-linux.html) to  install FlashTool so that I can root my Micromax Canavas HD. My Dev Enviornment is Ubuntu 12.04 LTE 64 bit with support libs for 32 architecture. I as well changed the 80-persistent-usb.rules files to:

```
# This file was automatically generated by the /lib/udev/write_net_rules
# program, run by the persistent-net-generator.rules rules file.
#
# You can modify it, as long as you keep each rule on a single
# line, and change only the value of the NAME= key.

# PCI device 0x10ec:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.1/0000:03:00.0 (r8169)
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ACTION=="add", SYSFS{idVendor}=="0bb4", SYSFS{idProduct}=="*", MODE="0777"
```

My vendor reflects the Micromax Identification(Changed the vendor part `SYSFS{idVendor}=="0bb4"`). However when I run the tool by issuing the command:

```
./FlashTool
```

I get the following message:

```
Not running as root but Sony/SonyEriccson Vendor ID found on your udev rules
if Flashing didn't work well, run flashtool as root
JAVA_HOME not set. Using default value : ./x10flasher_lib/linjre64
```

And the Flash tool GUI openes with all sorts of Sony Xperia phones listed. Any Idea where I might be going wrong and why my specific device is not opening?

**Edit:** I tried to set [JAVA_HOME like as discussed here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/399809/how-do-i-set-up-java-path?noredirect=1#comment513272_399809)

*Result:*

```
Johndoe@pc-dev-a147:~/Downloads/Softwares/FlashTool$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-sun
Johndoe@pc-dev-a147:~/Downloads/Softwares/FlashTool$ sudo su
[sudo] password for Johndoe: 
root@pc-dev-a147:/home/Johndoe/Downloads/Softwares/FlashTool# ./FlashTool
Running as root.
#
[thread 140425866192640 also had an error]
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fb7221a8a70, pid=3958, tid=140424834840320
#
# JRE version: 6.0_27-b27
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (20.0-b12 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Derivative: IcedTea6 1.12.6
# Distribution: Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, package 6b27-1.12.6-1ubuntu0.12.04.4
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libdbus-1.so.3+0x1da70][thread 140424832734976 also had an error]
# [ timer expired, abort... ]
Aborted (core dumped)
```

The FLashTool starts but, I still get Sony models.

Comment: The first step is to define the `JAVA_Home` system variable.